# Some Route Resource Not Working in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-4

I cannot find the problem using

```
$routes->resource
```

**Please help me figure out what is the problem.**

This is how I put my routes resource in config routes :

```
$routes->resource('ApiManageBanner', ['controller' =>'App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageBanner']); // get, put, create, delete
```

Recently I just move all my project to the newest codeigniter 4 **version 4.2.6** from the previous **version 4.1.2**

This is my controllers :

```
<?php
 
 namespace App\Controllers\ApiData;

 use App\Controllers\BaseController;
 use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
 use Codeigniter\API\ResponseTrait;
 


class ApiManageBanner extends ResourceController
{    
    use ResponseTrait;
    function __construct()
    {       

    }
    

    // equal to get    
    public function index() {    

        echo "Test";       
        
    }
    
        
    // equal to post
    public function create() {
            

    }

    // equal to get
    public function show($id = null) {                
      
    }

    // equal to put    
    public function update($id = null) {
        
    }
    

    // equal to delete
    public function delete($id = null) {        
       
        
    }

}
```

I just try a simple to echo "Test".

But I got this error :

[image]

I search everywhere but cannot find the problem related to the error.

If I change the routes name to **'ApiManageBanners'** using **'s'** :

```
$routes->resource('ApiManageBanners', ['controller' =>'App\Controllers\ApiData\ApiManageBanner']); // get, put, create, delete
```

**It is working.**

> But I cannot change my routes name because my application is reading
> 'ApiManageBanner' not 'ApiManageBanners'

I am very curious what cause the problem. It is not working for almost all my resources api controller routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. According to the error it is related to session. When I check all my file. I found that I always init the :

**$this->Session = \Config\Services::session();**

In all my controller and model __construct();

```
function __construct()
    {
                                
        $this->Session = \Config\Services::session();
                
    }
```

So I remove it and init globaly in BaseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 */
abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instance of the main Request object.
     *
     * @var CLIRequest|IncomingRequest
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers =   [''];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.

        // E.g.: $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->session = \Config\Services::session();       
        $this->language = \Config\Services::language();
        $this->language->setLocale($this->session->lang);
    }
}
```

Then the error is gone.